# SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h file not found while archiving

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, build, archive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sdwebimage: UIImageView+WebCache.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042569/sdwebimage-uiimageviewwebcache-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Just to start off. This is a duplicate question from this: [lexical or preprocessor issue file not found occurs while archiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925539/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-occurs-while-archiving)

Problem is that his solution doesn't work for me. I have gone through the installation document twice and it works if i set it to simulator 5.1.

Right now i want to archive it to send it in for the review.

If i select (app name -> iPhone 5.1 Simulator) it works. I can build it and i can test it.

If i select (app name -> iOS Device) it stops working and i get the same error as in the other post.

I have tried everything i can think off without any result.

Is it normal that it's called iOS Device? It had to be selected for me to be able to press archive.

I have followed Apples guide to publish my app. So i have added the extra Release settings( App store release settings), set my developer id, created an extra scheme called app name-AppStore, set the archive to use the appstore release settings. But nothing works, except if i switch over to iPhone 5.1 Simulator. Then it builds just fine and launches the simulator.

Any ideas? I am out. Have gone through all i can find on the net but it still doesn't work.

Also no idea what i am suppose to do with this information (from the post above):
"and make sure your User header paths are pointing to the Framework."

How?

Comment: You can find the ans to this [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042569/sdwebimage-uiimageviewwebcache-h-no-such-file-or-directory/9043199#9043199)